# Links to Facebook and Twitter

Tags: support

Sometimes I am invited to post a link to my answer to Facebook and Twitter and other times I am not. What decides?

Comment: See a related question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531/disable-share-a-link-popup

Comment: Thank you. I rather like the idea of being able to share my answers on Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: @tim that is for questions, not answers, so it's not relevant

Answer (score 2):

See

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80910/1

This only appears:

- a random percent of the time, decreasing chance with greater reputation
- on your posts
- if they are greater than 400 characters in length
- for 1 hour after posting